# Perl Regular Expression String Replacement

Tags: perl

I am trying to replace all occurrences of ANY value between two single quotes, including escaped single quotes. The following works quite well, except when an escaped single quote is found. This makes sense, but is there a way around it. I want to replace ALL characters between single quotes.

```
$ echo "'blah\'blah'" | perl -pe s/"'"[^"'"]*"'"/stuff/g
stuffblah'
```

I would like to just see:

```
stuff
```

Comment: This would be a fine job for [Text::Balanced](http://p3rl.org/Text::Balanced) instead of a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of our quotes, we want to allow the following tokens

1. all non-quote characters `[^']` or
2. all escaped quotes `\'`, encoded as `\\'` or
3. all escaped backslashes `\\`, encoded as `\\\\`. We need this extra rule to represent *all* possible data.

The *or* in regexes is denoted by the pipe character `|`, and we bracket these possible tokens with parens to group them for our iteration:

```
( \\\\ | \\' | [^'] )*
```

or perhaps more clearly showing what can be escaped:

```
( \\[\\'] | [^'] )*
```

Now we just pack this into quotes, and make the grouping parens non-saving (no variables `$1` etc need to be created), and we have

```
s {' (?: \\[\\'] | [^'] )* '}
  {stuff}gx
```

Note the use of the `/x` modifier to include non-semantic whitespace for better readability.

#### Edit: Perl one-liners

All one-liners were tested unter `bash`. Other shells will display other quoting horrors.
In the next line, the unescaped regex is provided.

This one-liner matches single quotes, as specified:

```
perl -pe"s/'(?:\\\\[\\\\']|[^'])*'/stuff/g"
         s/'(?:\\  [\\']  |[^'])*'/stuff/gx
```

doubling the backslashes is done to accomodate for shell escaping.

This one-liner matches double quotes:

```
perl -pe"s/\"(?:\\\\[\\\\\"]|[^\"])*\"/stuff/g"
         s/ "(?:\\  [\\"]   |[^"] )* "/stuff/gx
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, and it makes good sense. The problem is, how do I integrate your recommendation into the: perl -pe ... syntax.

Comment: @user1687556 that depends on what command line/shell you are using. In the bash shell, I would choose the `"` delimiter and write `perl -pe"s/'(?:[^']|\\[\\'])*'/stuff/g"` or the `'` delimiter and do some *ugly* escaping: `perl -pe's/\'(?:[^\']|\\[\\\'])*\'/stuff/g'`. I have too little experience to grok Windows' cmd.exe or other shells.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance, but your suggestion does not work as planned: echo "'blahblah\' asdasdf'"|perl -pe"s/'(?:[^']|\\[\\'])*'/stuff/g"  yields => stuff asdasdf' .I am using bash.

Comment: You are a genius. With a little scrubbing, this worked like a champ:  perl -pe s/"'"\([^']|[\\\\]|[\\']\)*"'"/stuff/g

Comment: @user1687556 Wrong, I'm a complete moron. After doubling the backslashes and (more importantly) putting the `[^']` case at the end, I found that this works as well: `echo "'blahblah\' asdasdf'"|perl -pe"s/'(?:\\\\[\\\\']|[^'])*'/stuff/g"
`

Comment: You seriously rock. Thanks again. Now, if we want to do the same thing with double quoted strings, it appears we cannot replace the delimiter ,etc. Any feedback there would be of great value should I encounter this requirement in the future.

Comment: @user1687556 something like this? `echo 'foo"blahblah\" asdasdf" bar'|perl -pe"s/\"(?:\\\\[\\\\\"]|[^\"])*\"/stuff/g"` This code severly suffers from the two escaping layers in the shell and the regex engine, but it works ;-) And this regex accepts both single- and double quoted strings: `perl -pe"s/([\"'])(?:\\\\[\\\\\"]|[^\"])*\\1/stuff/g"`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is only one single quote between the two blahs, so that when the first 'blah' is replaced the second blah' is no longer bounded by single quotes. If  you want to allow for escaped single quotes do this:

```
 s/\\?'[^']*'/stuff/g
```